# Is there any advantages of using Javascript's prototypical inheritance in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say I have 2 scenarios in Javascript (NodeJS):

**Scenario 1 :**

```
var obj = {};

obj.getAll = function(..) {...};

obj.getOne = function(..){...};

module.exports = obj;
```

and I use `obj` in the code that invokes this module.

VS something along the lines of:

**Scenario 2:**

```
var constructor = function(){};

constructor.prototype.findAll = function(..){...};

constructor.prototype.findOne = function(..){...};

module.exports = constructor;
```

In the code that invokes this module, I create an object from `constructor` as per my need basis and use it.

Does Scenario 2 have any advantages over Scenario 1?

Comment: They're not equivalent. First one: `require('module').getAll()` second one: `new (require('module')).findAll()`. Whether that's desired is up to you to judge.

Comment: @RobW: I understand the difference. My question is, does scenario 2 offer any advantages over scenario 1 in terms of memory usage or performance or maintenance etc?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your module.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Could you elaborate? I want to require the module and use it in other parts of my code, obviously! :)

Comment: Yes, indeed! For example, something like jQuery or a XMLHttpRequest wrapper would probably be better as a constructor, while something like a JSON module (pretending one didn't already exist) would be better off as an object. The fact that you're placing your code into a module doesn't significantly change your choice in that regard.

Comment: Unless you need multiple instances Scenario 1 is the way to go. Performance is not relevant here since it all comes down to use-case. If you need to create multiple instances, use a prototype. if not, don't use a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of memory usage or performance, the answer is "it's negligible". Since you're just creating a single object and no matter how many times you'd require the module you'd always get the same instance (b/c of module caching).

After that it just comes down to what you want the interface to the module to be.

Personally I think the prototypal inheritance pattern in this case seems a bit weird, and don't really see any benefits.